# How are linux package are update internally is there a writeup around it

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I work for a company that manage their own debian mirror. Today I was looking to update one of our packages on staging server i.e **vnstat**.

The currently installed version is `1.18-2` and latest version `2.6-1` (atleast that is latest on my local machine) or `2.9.1` if we go by [this](http://debian.mirror.net.in/debian/pool/main/v/vnstat/) standard.

So clearly we had a old version of **vnstat** running but when I try to update it the package manager refuse to update it with following msg **vnstat is already the newest version (1.18-2)**

```
sudo apt-get upgrade vnstat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
vnstat is already the newest version (1.18-2).
```

But when I observe my organisation official mirror I see the deb package with version 2.6-3.deb and 2.9-1.deb inside the **pool** directory.

So I want to understand how the package update are handle internally. In order to understand why the update is not get performed.

We rely on package manager for any update on our production so manual upgrade is not an options.

```
cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

The only thing I can speculate is that 2.6-1 requires a **libc6 (>= 2.29)**

```
// ran on my local machine.
apt-cache show vnstat
Package: vnstat
Architecture: amd64
Version: 2.6-1
...
Pre-Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.54~)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29), libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.7.6.1), adduser, lsb-base
```

while we are running on `2.28-10`

```
ldd --version ldd
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10+deb10u1) 2.28
```

Comment: *Enterprise* Linux distributions are not designed to be bleeding edge, but to provide long term stability and support of all components they ship for a specific distribution release.

As longs as the distribution release remains supported: Necessary security updates (and sometimes new features) get **backported** rather upgrading to a newer upstream version with new features. - see for example : https://serverfault.com/a/1092615/37681 - for Debian the specifics are different, the concepts the same

Comment: How did you upgrade the package?  Did you install it in your company's package repo, or somewhere else?  If it was in your company's repo, did you update the repo's index files to show the presence of the new package?

Comment: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade vnstat